# How can I reload all buffers at once?

Tags: buffers, load

When working on a feature branch in `git`, I frequently need to stash my changes to commit a bug fix to the main branch. When I'm done working on the changes, I `git stash pop`, which updates the timestamps on the files.

Even though the files are identical, the next time I try to save, I get:

> WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it!!!
>
> Do you really want to write to it (y/n)?

I don't want to automatically reload the file every time it changes on disk, only when I `git stash pop`.

Right now, I manually reload each buffer individually (`:e`). Is there any way I can do this in one command?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

See `:help bufdo` for what you want to do.  It will execute a command in each buffer in the buffer list.  For example:

```
:bufdo e
```

You may also want to look at `:help noconfirm` to disable the confirmation dialog before issueing the `bufdo` command

```
:set noconfirm
```

and reenabling it after the `bufdo` command.

```
:set confirm
```

Comment: To force, try: `:bufdo! e`.

Comment: and without printing messages on screen :silent! bufdo e

Comment: @kenorb I'm surprised it's not `:bufdo e!`.   Because to edit a different file in a buffer that has unsaved changes, without prompting, we can do `e! file`. It's the `e` that needs forcing, not the `bufdo` iteration.

Comment: There is a problem with `:bufdo e`. It brings the last buffer visited into the foreground. What if you want to reload buffers without changing which buffer is current? I use a buffer manager with a LRU display: recently viewed buffers closer to top. This `:bufdo e` messes with it; it visits every buffer and makes it the most recent buffer.

Answer (score 22):

You can do this with the `:checktime` command. From the [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:checktime):

```
:checkt[ime]        Check if any buffers were changed outside of Vim.
                    This checks and warns you if you would end up with two
                    versions of a file.
```

The command will ask you what to do for each buffer the file of which has a changed timestamp. To disable this for files that haven't changed you can do `:set autoread` to force vim to just reload them. vim **will** ask you if the contents between the buffer and the file on disk have changed.

You can setup a map like the following for ease of use:

```
nnoremap <F5> :checktime<CR>
```

Comment: Here is some bonus information that is not really part of the answer: For me, on OpenSUSE, gvim (the GTK GUI for vim) does this automatically when it gains focus. I don't really know why it does it and I haven't checked on other systems but I thought it might be useful as an extra. Maybe someelse can confirm?

Comment: This is really helpful! What I did on my end was to integrate this command as part of my tab switching shortcuts. i.e. `nnoremap tl :tabnext<CR>:checktime<CR>`

Comment: @tokoyami, the feature you have in `gvim` may be related to `FocusGained` event in `vim`. You can find some related info here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383044/99801.

Comment: `:checktime` will not check hidden buffers, which [sometimes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/39820/1553) might matter.

Comment: `:checktime` is not reliable for me. I saw it work, but right now, I have a buffer whose file was externally modified. Vim knows this. If I do `:w` in that buffer, it produces the warning that the file was modified by another program. Yet `:checktime` does nothing.  I ran it before trying `:w`.   If I abort the `:w` operation, and try `:checktime` again, again nothing, and then `:w` again produces the warning.  This is Vim 8.0 on Ubuntu 18; not latest/greatest. The buffer is not hidden. This reproduces when that buffer is current and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

A point that I think is relevant here. Which basically comes down to, "Why would one bother?" And helps to decide which solution to choose.

Let me start with terminology. There are active buffers (buffers which are open in some window, even if the window is not visible at the moment, e.g. on a different tab). When you abandon a buffer `b` (switch to some other buffer, or close some window, and `b` is no longer displayed in any window, including the non-visible ones), `b` becomes hidden if `&hidden` and unloaded otherwise.

From what I can see after executing a shell command (`!:`) `vim` does `checktime`. That is, it checks every active buffer and asks if the user wants to reload it (`:bufdo` executes a command in every buffer, including hidden and unloaded).

`vim` also checks if a buffer needs to be reloaded when the user switches to it. If the buffer was unloaded, it simply loads it (which makes sense). If the user switches to a hidden buffer, `vim` asks if the buffer should be reloaded.

When you do `:lvim` `vim` uses:

- content in the buffers (possibly stale) in case of active and hidden buffers
- content on the disk if case of unloaded buffers

Now let's say you're working on a project, have an active buffer `b` and switch to some other commit (`:!git checkout ...`). In this case `vim` asks you if you want to reload `b` if it was changed.

Let's say `b` was hidden, and before the switch a variable `someName` was mentioned in the file. But after the switch the variable is named `someOtherName`. `vim` will not ask you if you want to reload `b`. Then you do `:lvim someOtherName **/*`, and in this case `vim` will not find matches in `b`.

This is no argument against hidden buffers, but something to be aware of.

Comment: > *If the user switches to a hidden buffer, vim asks if the buffer should be reloaded* This is false. If a file is externally modified, Vim will switch to that buffer without any fuss. It will let you perform modifications and only when you save with `:w` will it then say, oh, that had been modified by an outside program, are you sure you want to clobber that ...

Comment: This question is about how to tell Vim that files have been externally modified and just sync all the buffers to the new files, to prevent the above problem.

Comment: @Kaz If you can't reproduce it then your buffer was likely not hidden. Try the [following steps](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/79011592fbeee1de8f8d0dec627ddb35) (it creates `/tmp/a`). The last command makes `vim` ask to reload the file.