# Reloading buffers silently after an executed script changes the underlying files directly

Tags: buffers, edit

I'm wrapping a command line script in a function and then in a command, which supplies this script with 2 arguments:

```
nnoremap <leader>G :BxSedRi 'src/', 's/\<<C-r><C-w>\>
    fun! BxSedRi(Dir,Arg)
        :if len(getbufinfo({'bufmodified': 1}))
            :throw "Must not have modified buffers"
        :endif
        :execute ":silent! !sed_Ri@bx" shellescape(a:Dir) shellescape(a:Arg)
        :bufdo! e!
        :redraw!
    endfun
    command! -nargs=+ BxSedRi call BxSedRi(<args>)
```

After the script, I was hoping for `:bufdo! e!` and `:redraw!` to silently reload all my buffers as the underlying files might have been changed by the script.

However, I am still getting these prompts:

```
W11: Warning: File "..." has changed since editing started                                                                                                                                │
See ":help W11" for more info.                                                                                                                                                                                 │
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

How can I get rid them and just reload all buffers silently?

Comment: Question: is your function running a sed in-place edit on all files in a dir? With a substitute? What if I told you there was a vim-native way to do something very similar?

Comment: Yes. Recursively on the given directory and with some laziness so that files that wouldn't change aren't touched. I'd be happy to learn how to also do it the vim way, of course! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like instead of `:bufdo! e!` (which also caused buffer highlighting to disappear: [Syntax highlighting is gone after :bufdo :e](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5225/syntax-highlighting-is-gone-after-bufdo-e)) I needed to do `:bufdo! checktime` with the `autoread` option locally disabled:

```
    :let ar = &autoread
    :set autoread
    :bufdo! checktime
    :redraw!
    :let &autoread=&ar
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's two vim versions of the "recursive, lazy, sed substitute" that the function is performing.

Both involve the same technique: filling one of vim's special lists and then calling the corresponding `do` command.

### Using the `arglist`

The `arglist` can be filled with files and traversed with `:next`, `:prev`, and a few other commands. Conveniently, we can run commands on all files in it with `:argdo`.

In order to avoid messing with the global `arglist`, we'll open a new window and use `:arglocal`:

```
:new
:arglocal …
```

What to but in the `…` depends, but in this case let's grab all files under `src` (this can be a bit slow on large directories):

```
:arglocal src/**/*
```

(Unfortunately, this also finds directories; if you're interested in, say, `.c` files, you can add the extension and get better matches. Otherwise, you need something like `` :arglocal `find src -type f` `` on a *nix.)

Now substitute in `:argdo`, with `/e` for ignoring files with no match and `:update` to lazily write the changed files (don't forget `/g` if you need it):

```
:argdo %substitute/…/…/e | update
```

You can wrap it up in a function, if you want (have a look at `<f-args>`, too).

### Using the quickfix list.

Same idea, but more targeted.

In this case, we'll populate the quickfix list with `:vimgrep` or `:grep` (your choice; I use ripgrep, so while I use `:vimgrep` for searching buffers already in vim, I prefer `:grep` for general code searches).

```
:vimgrep /…/ src/**/*
" or, e.g.,
:grep -R … src
```

Now we can traverse all the entries with `:cdo` or all the files with `:cfdo` (optionally, filter the entries with `:help cfilter-plugin` first):

```
:cdo substitute/…/…/ | update
```

We don't need `/e` this time because `:substitute` will only be run on lines already matching the pattern; similarly, we don't need `/g` because all matching lines will be there.

Note that if you used `:vimgrep` and the pattern for the search and substitute are the same, you can write

```
:cdo substitute//…/ | update
```

---

Both solutions avoid modifying files outside of vim, so you don't run into checktime/edit issues.