# `a` append to buffer commands

Tags: command-line, buffers, load

Similar question, yet not duplicate of: [How can I reload all buffers at once?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/458/how-can-i-reload-all-buffers-at-once)

If `:wa` writes all, would not `:ea` be expected to reload all?

How could one script `:ea` to behave this way?

What are the cases when `a` append works or not?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why it's not a duplicate? Why don't the answers to the linked question work for you?

Comment: Is it just that you literally want to type `:ea`?

Comment: @Rich, why wouldn't I? If `:qa` is equivalent to `:bufdo q`, why isn't `:ea` as like? Not duplicate, it does not mention (possibility of?) the `a` append.

Comment: I wasn't second guessing your motivation: I just wasn't 100% sure what you were asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think D. Ben Knoble's guess is as good as any as to why `:editall` hasn't been implemented to do what you want it to. Note that `:ea` already has a function (It's short for `:earlier`), and it's unlikely that this will ever be changed, as that would break backwards compatability.

If you want to make `:ea` instead reload all the buffers, you can use an abbreviation:

```
:cabbrev <expr> ea (getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdpos() == 3) ? 'bufdo edit' : 'ea'
```

As for other commands that support an `a[ll]` suffix, here's a possibly incomplete list gleaned from the command: `:helpgrep :\k*all\>`:

- `:qa[ll]`
- `:wqa[ll]`
- `:doautoa[ll]`
- `:xa[ll]`
- `:ba[ll]`
- `:packl[oadall]`
- `:sal[l]`
- `:sba[ll]`
- `:spellr[epall]`
- `:al[l]`

(Just in case you weren't already aware of this, all command-line commands can be abbreviated to the shortest non-ambiguous prefix, hence the square brackets `[]` denoting the optional characters in the command.)

Comment: `:earlier Ns` is a new topic for me; and nice hack, thanks! Only third question missing: "What are the cases when `a` append works?"

Comment: @fde-capu See edit for a list that may or may not cover them all.

Answer (score 4):

While I cannot answer design questions, not being a designer, I would hazard a guess that `:wall` was provided as a shortcut for a very common operation (`:bufdo write` or similar), while we are left with `:bufdo` (and `:argdo`, `:cdo`, `:windo`, etc.) for the rest.

A user command:

```
command -bar -bang Eall bufdo<bang> edit<bang>
```

(You may not want both bangs; they do different things, so pick the ones that make sense to you.)

Comment: It makes sense that it came into being for sake of short cutting; though I still use `:bufdo e` a lot, and would be happy with the `:ea` implementation. I am sorry to not understand your "user command", would you please expand?

Comment: @fde-capu it defines the command `:Eall` to do what you want.

Comment: Ok, I guess questions about the command `command` would be off topic. :/

Comment: Not at all! Though I recommend reading `:help :command` ofc